# Como retornar um arquivo através da minha API configurada no ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, api

Desenvolvi uma API  que faz buscas de imagens e agora preciso entregar os arquivos para download, então criei o seguinte código:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Download(string id)
{
    Download download = new Download(id, apiUser);
    byte[] myDataBuffer = download.DownloadImage();

    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(myDataBuffer);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    return result;
}
```

Os bytes são recebidos certinho no método `DownloadImage()`, o problema está no `HttpResponseMessage` ai ok, coloco em produção e através de outro projeto tenho o seguinte código:

```
public static void DownloadNewImage(string id)
{

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.Resource = "Home/Download";
    request.AddParameter("id", id);
    RestResponse response = Execute(request, "url-do-site");
}

private static RestResponse Execute(RestRequest request, string url)
{
    var cliente = new RestClient(url);
    cliente.FollowRedirects = false;
    var response = cliente.Execute(request);          
    return (RestResponse)response;
}
```

Quando debugo o response, recebo o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que `ContentLength = -1` e quando abro o `Content` o que me  foi retornado é isso:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content:                    
System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent, Headers:
{
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream
}
```

Acredito que esteja retornando algo errando no método `Download` que retorna o `HttpResponseMessage`, e algum parametro está incorreto, alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Se usar o postman e dar um get na sua API no Home/Download com algum ID válido funciona? a imagem é retornada? Por que está usando o application/octet-stream?